# How to stop an object with the press of a button

Tags: android, eclipse

I am fairly new to programming and having a tough time with a small problem. I have created an object which is initialized easily and starts working, how do i stop that object from functioning.

Following is my code:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                animationFart();
                playRandomSound();

            }

            private void playRandomSound() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int randomInt = (new Random().nextInt(soundList.size()));
                int sound = soundList.get(randomInt);
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(btn.getContext(), sound);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();

                    }

                });
            }

        });
```

How can i stop  this with the press of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `MediaPlayer mp;` globally and use `mp.stop();`:

```
if (mp!=null && mp.isPlaying()) {
  mp.stop();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this class

```
public class AudioPlayer {

  private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

  public void play(Context context, int resId) {
    stop();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, resId);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            stop();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.start();
  }

  public void stop() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
  }

  public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer != null;
  }
}
```